# Naming a cursor dynamically

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, cursor

Is it possible to name a cursor dynamically?
Something like this:

> `CREATE PROCEDURE`dyn_cursor`(IN`query`TEXT, IN`name`TEXT)
>       READS SQL DATA
>       LANGUAGE SQL
>       COMMENT 'Simulate dynamic cursor'
>   BEGIN
>       DECLARE eof BOOL;
>       SET temp = 'cur_dyn'+`name
>       `DECLARE temp CURSOR FOR
>           SELECT * FROM dyn_view;`
>   ...

What I want is to achieve is to pass the name of the cursor as a input, can it be done?

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Cursors are namespaced within the context of a stored routine, so you can use the same name for different cursors in different routines.

Comment: @IkeWalker I an writing a dynamic cursor, which is implemented with the help of the dynamic view, adn for this we need to keep a lock on the view so that it is not replaced by different users, therefore I need to have a different cursor everytime I run this procedure.